# UDP packets sent to wrong IP?

Tags: networking, router, wireshark, udp

I have an IPTV box connected to my only router that assigned it a local IP `192.168.1.165`.

I tapped the LAN cable right next to tv box and recorded traffic in Wireshark. There I saw a remote IP from my video service provider sending me UDP packets with video data to IP `10.236.61.83`. Is this a virtual network inside my IPTV box?

How does the router know to send UDP packets to device with `192.168.1.165` so it can subsequently reach `10.236.61.83` from there? Shouldn’t the UDP packets have a destination IP `192.168.1.165` before they reach the tv box? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: “How does the router know” – the short answer is “routes”. However, are you sure you’re not mixing up source and destination?

Comment: I updated my question with a Wireshark screen showing the censored source IP from my video stream provider and my local IP. I can't find `192.168.1.165` that could explain how these packets reached the tv box.

Comment: Is your router and your IPTV service from your ISP? If so, they could have set up a special NAT private subnet just for IPTV streaming.

Comment: @Spiff Indeed, they are from the same company, part of a package deal. Is there a way I can verify this? Can I interact with a private subnet?

Comment: Start your sniffer and then power cycle your IPTV box, and watch for ARPs and DHCP traffic on the 10.x subnet.